# How to compare first column of two files and print the difference of second and third column?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, solaris

I want to compare first column of two different files and if there is a match, put the difference of second and third column of both files into a new file with first column as the matched entry.

`Output File = Matched,Difference of c2 and c3 of file1,Difference of c2 and c3 of file 2`

Example:

File 1

```
12,1,3 
13,2,4 
14,5,7
```

File 2

```
12,4,5
13,4,7
15,3,9
```

Desired Output File

```
12 -2 -1
13 -2 -3
```

Please tell me how may I do this. **File length is varying. File1 is of length 100 and File2 is of length 20**

Comment: [1](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134216/compare-two-files-based-on-a-column-and-print-it)
[2](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131981/compare-columns-in-a-one-file-and-print-the-count-of-matches)
[3](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134829/compare-two-columns-of-different-files-and-print-if-it-matches) @codeforester

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `awk` which is more suited for this.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}FNR==NR{array1[$1]=$2-$3; next}($1 in array1){array2[$1]=$2-$3}END{for (i in array2){print i,array1[i],array2[i]}}' file1 file2
12 -2 -1
13 -2 -3
```

If `awk` is not native in `Solaris`, Can you try `nawk` as, put the below contents in a file called `nawk_script.awk`

```
BEGIN{FS=","}
FNR==NR{array1[$1]=$2-$3; next}($1 in array1){array2[$1]=$2-$3}
END{for (i in array2){print i,array1[i],array2[i]}}
```

and run it as

```
nawk -f nawk_script.awk file1 file2
```

Comment: I am surely making a very stupid mistake. I am getting 
`awk: syntax error near line 1 
awk: bailing out near line 1`

Comment: @nainometer: `awk` may not be native in `Solaris`, Can you try `nawk` with the rest of the commands

Comment: Using nawk:
`nawk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
         >>> BEGIN{FS=, <<< 
nawk: illegal statement at source line 1
`

Comment: This is working well with a `sort -u` at the end :)
One last thing please, how may I use this inside an already prepared script which is generating the 2 files in the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132157/discussion-between-inian-and-nainometer).

Answer (score 1):

This will do it - it is pure bash and doesn't fork any sub-processes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# the following loop will end when an EOF is encountered on
# either of the two input files, whichever happens first.
while IFS=, read -r m1 m2 m3 <&3 && IFS=, read -r n1 n2 n3 <&4; do
  if [[ $m1 == $n1 ]]; then
    printf "%d %d %d\n" $m1 $((m2 - m3)) $((n2 - n3))
  fi
done 3< file1.txt 4< file2.txt
```

Output:

```
12 -2 -1
13 -2 -3
```

Comment: Unlike the `awk` based solution above, this solution doesn't keep anything in memory and it would much better with larger files.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using `paste` and `awk`-

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '{gsub(",", " " , $0)} {if ($1 == $4) print $1, $2-$3, $5-$6}'
```

Output-

```
12 -2 -1
13 -2 -3
```

Explanation-

The `paste` command pastes the files side by side. The `awk` `gsub` command changes the commas to spaces. The second brace in the `awk` checks if the first and fourth columns are the same and if they are, does the required subtraction.

Comment: `paste Data1.csv Data-3.csv | awk '{gsub(",", " " , $0)} {if ($1 == $4) print $1, $2-$3, $5-$6}'

awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1`

Answer (score 0):

In awk. If `$1` is not yet in array `a`, subtract and store the value to the array. If it already is, print the key, value in `a`, and the value of subtraction. Space before `13` was already in your data:

```
$ awk -F, '!($1 in a){ a[$1]=$2-$3; next } { $3=$2-$3; $2=a[$1] } 1' f1 f2
12 -2 -1
 13 -2 -3
```